# Row to column transformation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have this result set in MySQL :

```
ID          Type Email          Degignation  
1000000000  202 brijesh@abc.com Entrepreneur
1000000000  234 brijesh@abc.com Engineering,Development
1000000000  239 brijesh@abc.com CTO
```

I have many such tuples not only three .
I want Type to be column and last column to become row value for them . Like below

```
ID                202         234                     239        Email 
1000000000   Entrepreneur  Engineering,Development    CTO       brijesh@abc.com
```

Comment: Auto generate such a SELECT:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a pivot table. It's kind of awkward to produce:

```
SELECT ID, 
 MAX(CASE Type WHEN 202 THEN Degignation END) AS `202`
 MAX(CASE Type WHEN 234 THEN Degignation END) AS `234`
 MAX(CASE Type WHEN 239 THEN Degignation END) AS `239`
 Email
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ID, Email
```

Note that you must know all the distinct `Type` values before you write the query. SQL doesn't allow a result set to add more columns dynamically as it discovers data values in the table. Columns must be fixed at query prepare time.

Answer (score 1):

Although Bill Karwin's answer is right query must know the defined set of columns but for a dynamic pivot query there is a hack way by using [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
  CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN `Type` = ''',
         `Type`, 
         ''' THEN Degignation END) `Type_',
         `Type`,
         '`'
         )

 )
  INTO @sql
  FROM t;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ID, ', @sql, ', Email 
                     FROM t 
                    GROUP BY ID,Email');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[**See Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/100ec/9)

---

> But as using [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) it has default limit of 1024
>   characters to concatenate and the remaining result will be truncated so
>   if there is lots of distinct types you have then this will
>   tricky,Although you can increase the limit for [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)
>   length constraint as mentioned in manual but it also has a dependency
>   on [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)