# Error in stored procedure Pivot using MySql version 8.0.17

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, pivot

Unfortunately `MySQL` does not have a `PIVOT` function which is basically for what I trying to do.

I need on the return set rows values as column name using the stored procedure below this link credits @Akina

[MySQL pivot tables - rows to colums . Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135211/mysql-pivot-tables-rows-to-colums-query/66136355#66136355)

But I have an error using

```
CALL PIVOT('sourcetable', 'contents', 'sUn', 'contents')
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '' ) ) parsed' at line 16 Time: 0,586s

This is the MySql table

```
+---------+----------+
| sUn     | contents |
+---------+----------+
| Area NO | 1234567  |
| Zone S  | 1234568  |
| Zone N  | 1234560  |
| Zone I  | 1234561  |
| Zone C  | 1234562  |
| Zone G  | 1234566  |
| Zone V  | 1234564  |
| Zone B  | 1234565  |
| Zone A  | 1234569  |
| CR      | 1234562  |
| ESA     | 1234561  |
| EPI     | 1234564  |
| SV      | 1234563  |
| SA      | 1234567  |
+---------+----------+
```

And this the `to_columnslist` view

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    concat( '`', `t_table`.`sUn`, '` VARCHAR(255) path \'$."', `t_table`.`sUn`, '"\'' ) AS `line` 
FROM `t_table`;
+--------------------------------------------+
| line                                       |
+--------------------------------------------+
| `Area NO` VARCHAR(255) path '$."Area NO"'  |
| `Zone S` VARCHAR(255) path '$."Zone S"'    |
| `Zone N` VARCHAR(255) path '$."Zone N"'    |
| `Zone I` VARCHAR(255) path '$."Zone I"'    |
| `Zone C` VARCHAR(255) path '$."Zone C"'    |
| `Zone G` VARCHAR(255) path '$."Zone G"'    |
| `Zone V` VARCHAR(255) path '$."Zone V"'    |
| `Zone B` VARCHAR(255) path '$."Zone B"'    |
| `Zone A` VARCHAR(255) path '$."Zone A"'    |
| `CR` VARCHAR(255) path '$."CR"'            |
| `ESA` VARCHAR(255) path '$."ESA"'          |
| `EPI` VARCHAR(255) path '$."EPI"'          |
| `SV` VARCHAR(255) path '$."SV"'            |
| `SA` VARCHAR(255) path '$."SA"'            |
+--------------------------------------------+
14 rows in set (0.11 sec)
```

Pls, help me to do it.

Comment: Please publish your procedure code as text -(we have no idea if the code in the link is the code in question)

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks I have tried publish my procedure but the question is not inserted. For this I have posted the link

Comment: If the code is exactly as in link you may need to set delimiters.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: I would not recommend Akina's solution. At least not with more than one client at a time. Since it creates a VIEW on the fly, two ore more clients who try to do that concurrently will conflict.

Comment: @BillKarwin okay you recommend ?

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks with delimiter i have error syntax in sp

Comment: I suggest the solution I gave here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25594902/20860

Comment: @BillKarwin Okay, many thanks for this help