# MySQL - Grouping and Pivot Table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot, pivot-table

so in MySQL I have a table like:

| date | account | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 1 | 3000 |
| 2021-01 | 2 | 2100 |
| 2021-01 | 3 | 1800 |
| 2021-02 | 1 | 3500 |
| 2021-02 | 2 | 1500 |
| 2021-02 | 3 | 2500 |

since it has 3 different accounts on 2 different date, I want to group it by date and account then count average so the table would be like:

| date | account1 | account2 | account3 | average_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 3000 | 2100 | 1800 | 2300 |
| 2021-02 | 3500 | 1500 | 2200 | 2400 |

what do you think the best query to achieve the result to convert account rows into columns in MySQL?

Comment: What have you tried? Questions about pivoting in MySQL have been answered many times on Stack Overflow. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594902/row-to-column-transformation-in-mysql/25594969#25594969

Comment: First post on stack overflow, actually at first i don't even know if this is called pivot, i searched like 'how to turn rows into columns on MySQL' but now i know if it's called pivot and glad to find so much answers related to my question. thank You!!